# Is there a reason why not deactivate embed tags in Wordpress in 2019?

Tags: wordpress, oembed

Is there any reason why oEmbed shouldn't be disabled when providing Open Graph tags?

Hi,

I noticed that LinkedIn uses the value from the oEmbed and not the provided Open Graph tags on a WordPress page. To prevent confusion and reduce the http requests, I deregistered the wp-embed scripts. So far I didn't notice anywhere the were missing. Is there a reason why still providing them in 2019 when you have og tags set?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, maybe the reason is Facebook is probably shutting down its API (for giving gour friends’ data to apps)... I read that on the internet.

[Facebook OG v3.3 changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog#v2_0_login)